# Find all differential functions for which along any line of the family

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, differential

Find all differential functions for which along any line of the family ${\ln}^{2}r- {\varphi}^{2} = c$  retains its value $|f(z)|$.

I tried to use the Cauchy-Riemann condition for polar coordinates. After that, I got a complex system, which I cannot solve yet. I suppose I need to use something else, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Do you mean holomorphic (differentiable) functions?

Comment: @mjw yes, it's what I meant

Comment: If the magnitude of a holomorphic function $f$ is constant along a curve, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: @mjw the point is that the modulus is constant, not $f$

Comment: $f$ holomorphic and $|f|$ constant on a curve $\Rightarrow f $ constant.